# How to Pass on value on raw to js Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I want to show my stock inventory to my cart that uses AJAX raw codes, and I need help with passing certain values.

1.
Currently on my ajax-cart-template.liquid I can get values from my theme.js.liquid via calling with this syntax: `{{cartIndex}}`
that is defined in this theme.js.liquid:

```js
$.each(cart.items, function(index, product) {
  
            var prodImg;
            if (product.image !== null) {
              prodImg = product.image.replace(/(\.[^.]*)$/, "_180x$1");
            } else {
              prodImg = //
            }
  
            if (product.properties !== null) {
              $.each(product.properties, function(key, value) {
                if (key.charAt(0) === '_' || !value) {
                   delete product.properties[key];
                 }
              });
            }
  
            animation_row+=2;
  
            item = {
              key: product.key,
              url: product.url,
              img: prodImg,
              animationRow: animation_row,
              name: product.product_title,
              variation: product.variant_title,
              properties: product.properties,
              itemQty: product.quantity,
              price: theme.Currency.formatMoney(product.price, theme.settings.moneyFormat),
              discountedPrice: theme.Currency.formatMoney((product.price - (product.total_discount/product.quantity)), theme.settings.moneyFormat),
              discounts: product.discounts,
              discountsApplied: product.price === (product.price - product.total_discount) ? false : true,
              vendor: product.vendor,
              invStock: product.variant.inventory_quantity,
              cartIndex: index
            };
  
            items.push(item);
          });
```

However if I call on `{{invStock}}` it doesnt work. Any reason why?

2.

I tried going to the ajax-cart-template.liquid and ending the `{% raw %}` and calling the object itself is possible but I will need the index, which I can get from `{{ cartIndex }}`. However, I have no idea how to pass on `{{ cartIndex }}` to for example the following codes:

```
<div class="testing">
{% endraw %}
cart.items[{{cartIndex}}].variant.inventory_quantity
{% raw %}
</div>
```

How would I go in solving this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how Shopify works. Liquid is rendered at Shopify and dumped out to the browser as a giant string of HTML, JS and CSS.

So when you try and use JS you are running code AFTER the Liquid render. So if you need to some data from Liquid, render it out into a data structure you can use later when Javascript comes to life in the front-end.

A typical use of {% raw %}  {% endraw %} is when you are trying to output a template or some other data that has characters that Liquid rendering would screw up. So you probably don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Ok fair enough that the Liquid is rendered first.

what about my first question though?

1. In my js `product.variant.inventory_quantity` cannot be called?

2. How do you as quoted by you "render it out into a data structure"

Comment: product.variant seems wrong to me. A product has many variants, therefore the correct structure is product.variants[0] or product.variants[1] etc. So if you are trying to access a variant's inventory quantity, you first off have to pick one.

Comment: I finally figured it out, you were right that I had to render it out to a data structure I could use later. 

I found out that the object was not complete from the js end. The data cart.items that was being passed does not have the inventory_quantity in it, though they have others. (I did try with `variant[0]`) .

So I punched in a div and collect the data later on.

Comment: Ever since backbone style JS, I have built myself a little front-end helper that can take data from the Liquid, and make it available later to do clever Shopify front-end things. Pays off. That being said, I have seen some pretty horrible attempts by people to do the same, with no elegance, just major hackery! Many way to skin the cat, only some are performant and clean.